# Terraform predefined variable for the currently executing command type

Tags: terraform

Terraform has some built-in predefined variables for things like `path.module` (the filesystem path of the module where the expression is placed) and `terraform.workspace` (the name of the currently selected workspace).

Is there a variable to get the currently executing command? (i.e. 'plan', 'apply', 'import', etc.)

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: You would need a wrapper for this, since these are all subcommands from the CLI.